# Is there any method to detect outliers in non normally distributed data?

Tags: python, outliers

I am working on automation of time series analysis. In this I have to automate the process of detecting outliers in uni variate time series. So my data can be normally distributed or non-normally distributed.

I know grubb test and box plot which can be used to detect outliers but it is supposed to be for normal distributed data

Answer (score 0):

If you have an empirical distribution you can compute quantiles (for example, at 0.025 and 0.975) for this distribution. Then the values which are beyond the quantiles could be denoted as outliers. Beware this only will be useful for distributions which are bell shaped (not like the exponential).

In other cases you should beaware of the nunces of each distribution, for example, in the exponential or poisson, you should look only to the right part.

For more answers, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129274/outlier-detection-on-skewed-distributions